# Find vector $x \not= 0$ that satisfies the equation $Ax = x$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-equations

Given a matrix A:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

I have to find a vector $x \not= 0$ that satisfies the equation $Ax = x$.

I have no idea how to approach this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if the null space of $A-I$ is non trivial (that is , has non zero vectors). Use row reduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$Ax = x\iff Ax-Ix=0\iff (A-I)x=0$$

thus the original problem is equivalent to find the null space for

$$B=A-I= \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{3} & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \frac{1}{3} & 0 & -1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: How do I find the null space?

Comment: As suggested by copper.hat in his first comment, you can use RREF to solve $Bx=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You want an $x\in\mathrm{Null}(A-I)$. Note that each column of the matrix $A-I$ adds up to $0$.

Comment: sorry you were referring to columns and that's ok, but sorry, how can that be useful for the nullspace of $A-I$?